# Change color value in style programmatically android

Tags: android, styles

Good Day, I have this style:

```
<style name="ViewPagerTitleStrip">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

I would like to change textColor in this method:

```
void setFontColor(){
    SharedPreferences mPref = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_SETTINGS_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean colorPref = mPref.contains(Constants.USER_FONT_COLOR);
    if(colorPref){
        int color = mPref.getInt(Constants.USER_FONT_COLOR, -1);
        //Somewhere here
    }
}
```

How can I implement that that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change XML resources at runtime.

You can, however, get the color value from your SharedPreferences and apply it directly to the View.

For example, assuming your view has a `setTextColor()` method:

```
if (colorPref) {
    int color = mPref.getInt(Constants.USER_FONT_COLOR, -1);
    titleStrip.setTextColor(color);
}
```

Comment: `PagerTabStrip` is a subclass of `PagerTitleStrip`, which does have a [`setTextColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html#setTextColor(int)) method.